# Minimum hardware and knowledge to study effects on live cells

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture, microscopy

I'm very interested to study the effects (or reactions) of different forces (magnetic fields, electric fields, etc) on living tissues/cells.

I know I have to have a living cell, the force applied and a microscope to study this but I do not know what kind of microscope will do and what kind of living organism to use (and how).

Any help to get me started will be of a tremendous help.

Comment: This is too broad of a question. You might wish to research first and come back when you have a specific question. Basically you are asking how to study cellular responses to physical stimuli - much broader than that in the field of cell biology is next to impossible. You might wish to visit our help center. Note that each stack has its own unique help center.

Comment: Quite contrary - this is a very beginner question in a vast domain. All I need is a simple/basic guidance for it. If every time you ask a question in a new field you are invited to take a walk (aka "search the internet") then we will never advance or start to become cautious with the people from that field.

Comment: A beginner question, yes, and that's fine. It's just too broad. It's an open-ended question and pob

Comment: I want to start with magnetic and electric fields only to see if it works and then to move to the more mysterious "qi" energy field....but I need to start from something...

Answer (score 1):

The "minimum hardware" you need consists of, at least:

- a microscope, as you said (which one exactly depends on what you want to do with it);
- whatever device you need to apply physical stimuli to cells (again, it depends on what you want to do exactly);
- a cell culture incubator;
- a cell culture hood to be able to work under sterile conditions;
- a dedicated cell culture room where to put the previous two items;
- a cell line to perform experiments on (actually, more likely several different cell lines).

Your question sounds like you are thinking about a personal project, but consider that none of these items is cheap. Add them up, and this project is really not affordable with the finances of an average individual.

The "minimum knowledge" you need consists of, at least:

- knowing how to do cell culture (mostly working under sterile conditions, which not only requires proper equipment but also very specialized technical skills);
- knowing (at least some of) the scientific literature about cellular responses to physical stimuli, because no lab is going to hire you as an intern if the project you have in mind has already been done and its results published years ago. You can search the biological scientific literature using [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/).

So, to me it seems that your best chance of starting this project is to find a cell biology lab with this equipment and expertise, and do an internship there. You can start by looking this up on the website of the university closest to you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - at least you split the problem into many more manageable ones. I think the basic start for me is to get the "basic kit" for this kind of experiments. For example minimum microscope specs, most basic cells (that are easy to grow and handle) and easy to observe.